# How to use the verb "play"?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, adverbs

A class has particularly enjoyed a film and want to see it again. Could they ask their teacher: "Could you play it again please?"

Comment: Lots of these "can a student say this" type questions today.   How have you researched the answers to these questions?  Why do you think there is a problem here?

Comment: I'm sorry to bother but i'm not a native speaker so some phrases may seem uncertain such as the use of the adverb "again" here or could it rather be "once more or "a second time" instead.

Comment: Hello there, I am just curious about this: You have asked 44 questions in total. 42 of those questions have been answered (1 or more answers). And you have not accepted an answer for any of those 42 questions. Sure, you are not required to select any answers as "accepted" but it feels a little unfair that people take time to answer them but their answers are never accepted.

Comment: I was not quite aware of that necessity, of the way it should be, or of the way your website works. Of course i do accept all of your answers and thank you all so very much for lending a hand!

Comment: @zenith3 That's alright :) Please note that you are not required to accept an answer (you can accept an answer by clicking the tick mark on its left, it turns green then). As the help center says, its an option for the OP. If an answer works/worked for you, then you can choose to accept it. Its not a "necessity". You can take a look at this to know more. https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: "Could you play it again please?" is absolutely correct and idiomatic. They could also say "Could you replay it, please?"

Comment: Can you [**screen**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/screen) the film again please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could they ask their teacher:

> "Could you play it again please?"

Of course they can. I don't see why not. To me, this is perfectly idiomatic. But how children ask this really depends on their understanding of the language and their age, I guess. If they are too young, they may just say "again".

They could also say:

> "Could you replay it, please?"

And they could also say:

> "Could you show it again, please?"

In this very straightforward case, both "can" and "could" work equally well.